# Russian words in cyrillic that look like english words?

Tags: правописание

Ie words like COP or HAM which have a similar spelling but a totally different meaning in russian or in english. Can you provide the back translation of the russian?

Comment: Are you trying to create a funny car registration plate?

Answer (score 6):

I've created two word lists from aspell's databases. I used the standard rules for Latin-Cyrillic symbol correspondence which defines symbols usable on Russian vehicle license plates: `ABEKMHOPCTYX`

The English word list:

```
aspell --lang=en dump master | egrep -i "^[ABEKMHOPCTYX]+$" | sed 's/.*/\U&/' | tr 'ABEKMHOPCTYX' `echo 'АВЕКМНОРСТУХ' | iconv -f utf-8 -t koi8-r` | iconv -f koi8-r -t utf-8 | sort > en-sorted.txt
```

The Russian word list:

```
aspell --lang=ru dump master | sed 's/\/.*//;s/.*/\U&/' | egrep -i '^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]+$' | sort > ru-sorted.txt
```

Comparison:

```
comm -12 en-sorted.txt ru-sorted.txt | awk '{print length, $0}' | sort -n | cut -d" " -f2-
```

This yields quite a long list with two five-letter matches:

> МЕССА
>   ТОТЕМ

and a handful of four-letter matches:

> АТОМ
>   ВАКЕ
>   ВЕЕР
>   ВЕЕТ
>   ВОСК
>   КАМА
>   МАМА
>   МЕТА
>   МОРЕ
>   МОСК
>   НАТЕ
>   РАСТ
>   СНОС
>   СОТЕ

*ВАКе* is apparently *ВАК (Высшая аттестационная комиссия)* in prepositional, and I don't have a slightest idea about what *моск* is, but otherwise the list looks legit.

Comment: МОСК is "Международное Общество Сознания Кришны".

Comment: @YellowSky: it's spelt in lowercase in the database

Comment: `Моск` is `мозг` in an Internet slang. http://lurkmore.to/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA

Comment: "А ВЕК МОНСТРУХ" легче запомнить чем по алфавиту)))

Comment: а Ваке это район в Тбилиси

Comment: Do not TOTEM, ATOM, MAMA etc mean the same in Russian and English?

Comment: @anixx: TOTEM, ATOM and MAMA do, etc do not (necessarily)

Answer (score 2):

***ВОР*** — thief.

***MAX*** — a swing or stroke.

***ОН*** — the pronoun "he".

Italicised lowercase (in most though not all typefaces) has a lot more, as **т** and **и** become part of it:

***роет*** — "[he/she/it] digs".

***сир*** — "sire" (not "sir", which is *сэр*), or obsoletely "is orphaned" (predicate form of *сирый*).

***соте*** — "to a cell" (in a beehive).

***тор*** — "torus". (The same word capitalised: ***Тор*** — Thor.)

In Times New Roman, lowercase italic *п* is identical to *n*, giving you ***nар*** "steam", ***nо*** "on, over", ***реn*** "of turnips", ***саn*** "glanders". (I'm replacing *п* with the Latin letter here.)

There must be many more and it's hard to come up with an exhaustive list.

Comment: `соте` - wrong definition, https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5 in a beehive it would be `соты`

Comment: @UVV соты? in dative singular? I did specify the form and there's no reason to exclude oblique cases. but you're right, it could also mean "sauté". didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

Besides mentioned word "Сор" there is also the word "Mycop" which normally means "Trash" but in the jargon - "the Policeman".

Answer (score 0):

`сор` is the obsolete word for garbage or litter. It's used quite rarely. Pronounced like [s o r]

`нам` is the pronoun meaning "us". Its transcription is [n ʌ m]

Comment: How come `сор` became obsolete?

Comment: @UVV, do you think it's used often enough? I can only remember an idiom `выносить сор из избы` where `сор` is presented. Also, the related verb `сорить` is current. But `сор` itself is out of use in everyday speech, IMHO.

Comment: Just because it's not used on daily basis doesn't mean it's obsolete. As you mentioned it's a noun from verb `сорить`

Comment: @UVV, it's a misunderstanding, I guess. Let's see an example. The American Heritage Dictionary describes the obsolete label thus: "The label obsolete is used with entry words and senses no longer in active use, except, for example, in literary quotations." That's exactly the same that I ment for `сор`. But you might got it like this word is no more.

Answer (score 0):

`НАТЕ` - take it

There was a rock band with that name in 80's.

Comment: There was also a Mayakovsky's poem НАТЕ, based exactly on the word play with the English word.

Comment: Do you have the poem? I've looked for it but can't find it. In Russian and in English if you do. Thanks very much.

Comment: @martin - I'm not sure whether Mayakovsky did mean the pun on the English 'hate', but here's the poem, 1913: http://www.stihi-rus.ru/1/Mayakovskiy/25.htm

Comment: I've seen HATE translated as 'Take it' or 'Take that'. does it have any other meanings like 'catch it' or 'get it'?

Answer (score 0):

[ОМОН](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMON), a system of special police units, looks like a mirror image of "HOMO", which in English is a [derogatory short form](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homo#Etymology) of "homosexual".

[Boing boing](http://boingboing.net/2013/08/15/look-at-the-interesting-badges.html) has a photo of the police, with their name visible.