# How can one translate the word "Нате"?

Tags: перевод

I've seen take it, take that, get and catch? Are all valid or are there other ways?

Answer (score 3):

These are all valid.

**На** is a particle you sometimes use in speech when "giving" something to a person, verbally encouraging them to "take, get" it. Often used in the beginning of a sentence, or as a one-word sentence. Its plural/polite form is *"нате"*, though, strictly speaking, their usage differs a bit.

This "take it" meaning gives rise to a few metaphorical uses in set expressions. In such expressions *на* and *нате* are not, as a rule, interchangeable.

Comment: Can I use HATE in the context of getting or catching a person. Or is only used in 'giving' to a person?

Comment: @martin You cannot. In its primary meaning it is used by a giver towards a person they give *something* to.

Answer (score 1):

It is interjection на in plural.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate it as "Here you are"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are all that three meanings in this word

Answer (score 0):

It's can be short form of russian girl name "Наталья", short form is "Ната".
Or "take it", how answer Shady_arc

Comment: A correction: it could be written on an envelope (To whom - Нате).

Answer (score -1):

Translate into what language? And  how the phrases you bring are connected with the word ***hate***?

Comment: try to read it in Russian :)

Comment: Oh,  clear! I read it in English! That is why I didn't get the point. )))

Comment: This question was probably inspired by http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/8623/5423